# Get the inserts

Tags: sql-server-2008, export

I want to know if I can get all the INSERTs that are inserted at my database, from once. 
Writing just once ... I want that shows me all the inserts with the data and everything that was inserted in the moment of insertion. Not just the data, but everything including the INSERTs, is this possible?

I'm using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two methods:

1) You could try using the new auditing features of SQL Server 2008 [How to: Create a Server Audit and Database Audit Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280424.aspx)

2) write an INSERT trigger for each table and send the INSERTED table to a common log.